# Regex to match backslash unless followed by _, %, ' or an odd number of backslashes

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex expression to select a backslash.

The problem is that I only want to select it if it's not followed by an odd number of backslashes, or one of the characters in this set: [_%']. I don't mind which backslash in the sequence is selected, first or last, I just need to select exactly one in the sequence (or each first/last in each sequence - there can be more in a single string).

Example nothing selected:

```
this is \\ my string
this is my string\\\\
this is my \\\\\\ string
this is \' my string
this is \_ my string
this \% is my string
this \'\_\\\% is my string
this is\\my string
this is my\\\_string
```

Example select first backslash (or last)

```
this is \ my string
this is \\\ my string
this is \\\\\ my string
this is\\\my string
```

In next example, two backslashes in total should be selected, the single one from the first block, and the first/last of the three backslashes in sequence:

```
this is \ my \\\ string
```

I semi did do it with expression `(?<!\\)\\(?!([_%']))`, except I don't know how to add the condition that it's not followed by an odd number of backslashes that would work with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt indeed only needs the additional logic for ensuring the odd number of backslashes.

So you could match the first backslash as follows:

- Assert that it is the first (there is no immediately preceding backslash) -- you already had this
- Assert that the number of backslashes *after* the match is even and not followed by any of the special characters, nor another backslash.

Regex:

```
(?<!\\)\\(?=(?:\\\\)*(?![\\'_%]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing, so this is what I'm reading from your description.

```
\\(?!['_%]|(?:\\\\)*\\(?!\\))
```

https://regex101.com/r/msGOzK/1

```
 \\                     # an escape
 (?!
    ['_%]               # not folled by these special characters
  |                     # or
    (?: \\\\ )*         # not followed by an odd number of escapes
    \\ 
    (?! \\ )
 )
```

Or, if you have an engine that does Atomic groups `(?< )`, the regex can be this.

```
\\(?!['_%]|(?>(?:\\\\)*)\\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/9wRJUg/1

Or, with PCRE or Perl engines you can use the possessive quantifier `*+`.

```
\\(?!['_%]|(?:\\\\)*+\\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/JIaGSM/1